# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception android

Tags: android, linux, flutter, gradle, build

Error: The argument type 'Future Function(PredictionModel)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)'.

- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'PredictionModel' is from 'package:haraka/services/Models/prediction_model.dart' ('lib/services/Models/prediction_model.dart').
  (PredictionModel value) async {
  ^
  lib/sendpackage/send.dart:154:57: Error: The argument type 'Row Function(BuildContext, PredictionModel)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, dynamic)'.
- 'Row' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart' ('../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart').
- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
- 'PredictionModel' is from 'package:haraka/services/Models/prediction_model.dart' ('lib/services/Models/prediction_model.dart').
- 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  itemBuilder: ((context,
  ^
  lib/sendpackage/send.dart:214:47: Error: The argument type 'void Function(PredictionModel)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(Object?)'.
- 'PredictionModel' is from 'package:haraka/services/Models/prediction_model.dart' ('lib/services/Models/prediction_model.dart').
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  (PredictionModel suggestion) {
  ^
  lib/sendpackage/send.dart:220:56: Error: The argument type 'Row Function(BuildContext, PredictionModel)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Object?)'.
- 'Row' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart' ('../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart').
- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
- 'PredictionModel' is from 'package:haraka/services/Models/prediction_model.dart' ('lib/services/Models/prediction_model.dart').
- 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  itemBuilder: (context,
  ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/home/mawi/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/home/mawi/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 58s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             60.0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.